# Count even and odd numbers and the totals (python)

Tags: python, loops

I'm having a hard time with my homework I think I'm close to an answer, but I'm stuck as of now. Basically we are supposed to input a high integer for the range, a low integer for the range and then input a number to find out the multiples for that number. While I was able to get the multiples of whatever number I typed, we are then supposed to count the even and odd numbers in the multiples printed and total them:

here's my code so far:

```
 def main():
        high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: ')) # Enter the high integer
        low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))   # Enter the lower integer
        num = int(input('Enter the integer for the multiples: '))   # Enter integer to find multiples

        def show_multiples():
                # Find the multiples of integer
                # and print them on same line
                for x in range(high, low, -1):
                        if (x % num) == 0:
                                print(x, end=' ')

                def isEven(x):
                        count = 0
                        total = 0
                        for count in range():
                                if (x % 2) == 0:
                                        count = count + 1
                                else:
                                        count = count + 1
                

                        print(count, 'even numbers total to')
                        print(count, 'odd numbers total to')
                isEven(x) 
        show_multiples()
main()
```

Am I close to an answer or am I way off?
New to python this is my first time using it for class.

### **EDIT:**

```
Here are the instructions for the homework:

Part 1: Write a program named multiples1.py that generates all multiples of a specified
integer within a specified consecutive range of integers. The main function in the program
should prompt the user to enter the upper and lower integers of the range and the integer
for which multiples will be found. A function named show_multiples should take these three
integers as arguments and use a repetition structure to display (on same line separated by
a space) the multiples in descending order. The show_multiples function is called inside
main. For this program, assume that the user enters range values for which multiples do exist.
SAMPLE RUN
Enter the high integer for the range 100
Enter the low integer for the range 20
Enter the integer for the multiples 15
90 75 60 45 30

Part 2: Make a copy of multiples1.py named multiples2.py. Modify the show_multiples
function so it both counts and totals the even multiples and the odd multiples. The
show_multiples function also prints the counts and sums. See sample run.
SAMPLE RUN
Enter the high integer for the range 100
Enter the low integer for the range 20
Enter the integer for the multiples 15
90 75 60 45 30 
3 even numbers total to 180
2 odd numbers total to 120

Part 3: Make another copy of multiples1.py named multiples3.py. Modify the show_multiples
function so that it creates and returns a list consisting of all of the multiples (even
and odd). The show_multiples function should print only "List was created", not the
multiples. Create another function named show_list that takes the list as its sole
argument. The show_list function should output the size of the list, display all of the
list elements, and output the average of the list accurate to two decimal places. See
sample run.
SAMPLE RUN
Enter the high integer for the range 100
Enter the low integer for the range 20
Enter the integer for the multiples 15
List was created
The list has 5 elements.
90 75 60 45 30
Average of multiples is 60.00
```

Comment: Well it depends, when you run it - do you get the answers you expect?

Comment: Looks like you are using the same count for even and odd numbers?

Comment: Yeah i am using the same count for even and odd numbers. Should i do a different count for each?

& Yes when i run it, it prints the multiples of the number I input. But after that it doesnt work.

Comment: if you are using the same count then you are counting the total of even and odd numbers, not separate counts.

Comment: Ok I fixed that and made an even_count and an odd_count. But it still fails because of the for loop range in the isEven function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down into its components.

- Get the numbers in the range of [X, Y] (both inclusive but this is not explicitly spelled out in the instructions.

  ```
  high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: ')) # Enter the high integer
  low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))   # Enter the lower integer
  num = int(input('Enter the integer for the multiples: '))   # Enter integer to find multiples

  multiples = []
  for value in range(high, low-1, -1):
      if value % num == 0:
          multiples.append(value)
  ```

  Now there are lots of ways to improve this (making it more Pythonic, and possibly improving the speed - especially for large deltas between low and high)... so let's make it more Pythonic first.

  ```
  multiples = [value for value in range(high, low-1, -1) if value % num == 0]
  ```

  and maybe even

  ```
  multiples = [value for value in range(high, low-1, -1) if not value % num]
  ```

  The speed improvement can come by finding the first multiple less than or equal to `high` (call it `first` in this example) and then making your multiples by doing

  ```
  multiples = list(range(first, low, -num))
  ```

  This solution skips over all of the intermediate numbers which you already know are not multiples.
- So we have the multiples, and we have them in descending order... great!  Now we want to get the numbers broken out into two groups, `odd` and `even`.  To do that we can use a bunch of clever tricks, or we can just do it the old fashioned way - iterate.

  ```
  odd, even = [], []
  for value in multiples:
      if value % 2 == 0:
          even.append(value)
      else:
          odd.append(value)
  ```
- Once we have `odd` and `even` populated with the corresponding values, we can calculate how many of each there are with the built-in `len` function which would look like this

  ```
  len(odd)
  len(even)
  ```
- And to get the sum, we can use the built-in `sum` function which looks like this

  ```
  sum(odd)
  sum(even)
  ```

So a working example of Part 2 would be:

```
def show_multiples(low, high, num):
    first = high // num * num # Divided the high by num and floor it (ie. 100 // 15 == 6) ... then mutiply by 6.
    # can be written as
    # first = (high // num) * num
    # if that is clearer

    multiples = list(range(first, low-1, -num)) # more efficient for large delta
    # OR
    # multiples = [value for value in range(high, low-1, -1) if not value % num]

    odd, even = [], []
    for value in multiples:
        if value % 2 == 0:
            even.append(value)
        else:
            odd.append(value)

    print(" ".join(map(str, multiples)))  # just some trickery to get a list of numbers to work with join
    # could also do this - the comma prevents a newline
    # for multiple in multiples:
    #     print(multiple),
    # print()

    print("{} even numbers total {}".format(len(even), sum(even))) # string.format
    print("{} odd numbers total {}".format(len(odd), sum(odd)))

def main():
    high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: ')) # Enter the high integer
    low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))   # Enter the lower integer
    num = int(input('Enter the @integer for the multiples: '))   # Enter integer to find multiples

    show_multiples(low, high, num)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**NOTE** 
I am still on Python2 so there may be some nuances between this code and Py3.  For instance, I am not sure you need to wrap `range` in a list like I do.  I wrote this for Py2, and converted what I knew needed converting to Py3.

**EDIT**
If you need to do it without lists... then this would be my approach

```
def show_multiples(low, high, num):
    even_count = 0
    odd_count = 0
    even_sum = 0
    odd_sum = 0

    for value in range(high, low-1, -1):
        if value % num:
            continue
        if value % 2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
            even_sum += value
        else:
            odd_count += 1
            odd_sum += value
        print(value),
    print

    print("{} even numbers total {}".format(even_count, even_sum))
    print( "{} odd numbers total {}".format(odd_count, odd_sum))

def main():
    high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: ')) # Enter the high integer
    low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))   # Enter the lower integer
    num = int(input('Enter the @integer for the multiples: '))   # Enter integer to find multiples

    show_multiples(low, high, num)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked i'm going back through the book now and reading up on the functions you and Ivan mentioned. also would there have been any way to do part 2 without a list? Just want to make sure. Because during part 3 is where my instructor wants us to do lists. Or does it not matter?

Comment: Sure you can do it without lists.  See my edit above.  Now you are just calculating the values like `even_count` and `even_sum` as you iterate in the same loop that you print the multiples.

Comment: @Brandon: If I answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the start of the answer.  Happy to help.  Don't just copy and paste for you homework... make sure you understand it.

Comment: Ok will do and yes i'm going over it now to make sure of that haha.

Answer (score 0):

First, why you are using nested function, it makes reading and understanding difficult. Next thing, pay attention to your even count calculations - it does nothing with multiplies, so it can't be correct by definition. More clear way is to save your multiplies somehow for printing and even count calculation. Also note that your function is called isEven, however, it not checks even or not number is, it counts something depending on x. It's bad practice. Your function names should clearly describe what they do. Then, look into your print statements. They print same variable with different info about it. Looks like typo. Here I post clear and stylish solution for your problem. If you're a newbie, probably you should learn some useful python functions as `filter`, and explore the difference within `range` and `xrange`. Also note, that lower-bound in the borders your specify is not included. To change that, use low-1 when calling xrange.

```
def get_multiplies(high, low, num):
    """Find the multiples of integer"""
    return filter(lambda x: x % num == 0, xrange(high, low, -1))

def isEven(x):
    return x % 2 == 0


def main():
        high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: ')) # Enter the high integer
        low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))   # Enter the lower integer
        num = int(input('Enter the integer for the multiples: '))   # Enter integer to find multiples

        multiplies = get_multiplies(high, low, num)
        # print multiplies on same line
        print ' '.join(str(m) for m in multiplies)
        even_count = len(filter(isEven, multiplies))

        print(even_count, 'even numbers total to')
        print(len(multiplies) - even_count, 'odd numbers total to')

main()
```

Comment: Yeah i'm a newbie to python. First week of class and I'm taking it online. I'll take a look at some of the functions you mentioned.

Comment: I posted the instructions of the homework to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code

```
  def show_multiples():
            # Find the multiples of integer
            # and print them on same line
            lst = []
            for x in range(low, high+1):
                    if (x % num) == 0:
                            #print x
                            lst.append(x)
            return lst

  def check_even_odd(lst):
          count = 0
          total = 0
          eventotal = 0
          oddtotal = 0
          for x in lst:
              if (x % 2) == 0:
                     count = count + 1
                     eventotal = eventotal + x
              else:
                     total = total + 1
                     oddtotal = oddtotal + x


          print(count, 'even numbers total to', eventotal)
          print(total, 'odd numbers total to', oddtotal)

  def main():
       high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: ')) # Enter the high integer
       low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))   # Enter the lower integer
       num = int(input('Enter the integer for the multiples: '))   # Enter integer to find multiples


       reslst = show_multiples()
       print reslst
       check_even_odd(reslst)
  main()
```

Comment: It's a bad design when function called `isEven` accepts a list and print something out.

Comment: @klass : there is no isEven here, using list is also one possible method to find out even and odd counts by considering two counters.

Comment: Yes, but my comment was for previous version of your code. As for current, much better design is to name function `count_even_odd(lst)` and `return eventotal, oddtotal`, and print nothing inside that function, but  get it in main method: `eventotal, oddtotal = count_even_odd(reslst)` and then print

Answer (score 0):

Write a Python program to take input of a positive number,
say N, with an appropriate prompt, from the user.
The user should be prompted again to enter the number until
the user enters a positive number.
Find the sum of first N odd numbers and first N even numbers.
Display both the sums with appropriate titles.

```
    n = int(input("enter n  no.... : "))
    sumOdd =0
    sumEven = 0
    for i in range (n) : 
        no = int(input("enter a positive number : "))
        if no > 0 :
            if no % 2 == 0 :
                sumEven = sumEven + no
            else :
                sumOdd = sumOdd + no
        else :
            print("exit.....")
            break
    print ("sum odd ==  ",sumOdd)
    print ("sum even ==  ",sumEven)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_it(seq):
    for i in seq:
        count = seq.count(i)
        if count%2 != 0:
            return i
            break
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.